# Incomprehensible data received from PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I have this problem reading "character varying" field data through a C# program from a PostgreSQL version 12 database table using npgsql.
This is the code I use:

```
   NpgsqlDataSource DataSource = NpgsqlDataSource.Create(connectionString);
   NpgsqlCommand command = DataSource.CreateCommand("SET client_encoding = 'UTF8'");
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();

   command = DataSource.CreateCommand(this.Config.PostgreSQL_CommandString);
       int righe= command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
       while (reader.Read())
       {
           var v = reader.GetValue(1);
       }
```

The field contains, for example, the value ""Stanley Kubrick"" and what is read by the program (v variable) is "1\0\0\0\u00042\0\0\0\u0004T\0\0\0p".

I have already tried modifying the encode/decode and installing the latest versions of the dlls, but the result does not change.
I would expect to be able to read the data correctly in readable format.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried configuring this on the connection-string instead (`;Client Encoding=UTF8`)? if the provider doesn't know that you've changed the encoding, it could do incorrect things

Comment: Yes, the result is always the same.

Comment: Why do you call ExecuteNonQuery() before ExeuteReader?

Comment: There should be nothing to read after executing a non-query.  You would think that would cause an error, rather that gibberish, though.

Comment: It's left over from one of my tests to give me the number of lines. As you can see, I then execute a new query with ExecuteReader.
Even if I remove the ExecuteNonQuery the result does not change.
I get the correct number of rows and fields, but in the fields I find the data written in the format I reported.
If I analyze the type of field I get that:
reader.GetFieldType(<field>) => String
reader.GetPostgresType(<field>) => character varying
So the data structure is correct, but the conversion from "character varying" to "String" is not done correctly.

Comment: Why are you using `reader.GetValue(1)`, instead of `reader.GetString(1)`?

Comment: Even with I get the same result: var v = reader.GetValue(1);   ==> "1\0\0\0\u00042\0\0\0\u0004T\0\0\0p"
var s = reader.GetString(1);   ==> "1\0\0\0\u00042\0\0\0\u0004T\0\0\0p"
var r = reader.GetTextReader(1).ReadToEnd();   ==> "1\0\0\0\u00042\0\0\0\u0004T\0\0\0p"
It gives me the impression that the value is 'masked'

Comment: What is your `server_encoding`?  When you say the value in the DB is eg "Stanley Kubrick", what are you using to see that (PGAdmin or something else)?

Comment: A full, runnable repro would be helpful here, including a SQL dump for creating the database and data.

Comment: The database encoding is "UTF8" and to access the data I use PGAdmin.
Below are the scripts for creating the database and table:

Comment: CREATE DATABASE "OPSI"
    WITH
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'Italian_Italy.1252'
    LC_CTYPE = 'Italian_Italy.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    IS_TEMPLATE = False;

ALTER DATABASE "OPSI"
    SET bytea_output TO 'escape';

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.film
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    titolo character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    regista character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    data_produzione date,
    CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.film
    OWNER to postgres;